# PHP Based Forum Software

Tags: php, forums

I have been wondering what PHP based forums software the stack**overflow** community likes/uses the most. Just so that people could make their own decision, when answering could you also leave a reason why?

Thank you to everyone who responds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never tried it myself, but maybe you are looking for something like [Vanilla Forums](http://vanillaforums.org/)

Comment: Hmm...I like it! It looks smooth, has forums, and user pages. Still checking it out, but you may have found what I am looking for..

Comment: Its got a nice documentation too, thanks!